# Show Button and Div on Event in Asp.net core with Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor-pages

I have two dropdown menus one for Categories and the other for SubCategories.  I have a partial view called _CreateProject that has the html for a post form to create a new project.  I have a button where on-click I would want it to display the form for creating a new project. However, I want the "Create Project" button to only be visible when a category and subcategory are selected and only display the _CreateProject partial when the button is clicked.

I have tried labeling the div's as hidden and then showing them with $(#id).show() but the div's are not being revealed.

These are my scripts and where I try to reveal the buttons:

```
<script>
                    //Populate SubCategory when Category changes
                    $(function () {
                        $("#Category").on("change", function () {
                            var categoryId = $(this).val();
                            $("#SubCategory").empty();
                            $("#SubCategory").append("<option value=''>---Select Subcategory---</option>");
                            $.getJSON(`?handler=SubCategories&categoryId=${categoryId}`, (data) => {
                                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                    $("#SubCategory").append(`<option value="${item.subCategoryId}">${item.subCategoryName}</option>`);
                                });
                            });
                        });

                        //try to show #partial on button click
                        $("#projectButton").click(function () {

                            $("#partial").show(); //try to reveal partial here

                        });



                        $("#SubCategory").on("change", function () {
                            $("#projectButton").show();  //try to show button here
                            var SubCategoryId = $(this).val;
                            $("#ProjectId").empty();
                            $.getJSON(`?handler=Projects&SubCategory=${SubCategoryId}`, (data) => {
                                             //...
```

This is the button as well as the div containing the partial:

```
<div hidden id="projectButton">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">New Project</button>
</div>

<div id="partial" hidden>
    <partial name="_CreateProject"/>
</div>
```

Category and SubCategory for reference

```
<label asp-for="Category">Category:  </label>
<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="Model.categorylist">
    <option value="">---Select Category---</option>
</select>


<label asp-for="SubCategory">Subcategory:</label>
<select asp-for="SubCategory"><option value="">---Select Subcategory---</option></select>
```

```
public void OnGet()
{

            categorylist = new SelectList(categoryService.GetCategories(), nameof(Category.CategoryId), nameof(Category.CategoryName));

}

//called by first jQuery
public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories()
{
            UserId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUserId"));
            return new JsonResult(categoryService.GetSubCategories(Category.CategoryId, UserId));

}
```

What is a good way to accomplish this?  I am new to Jquery so perhaps there can be some sort of "error" there?  Thanks

Comment: "perhaps there can be some sort of syntax error" ...if you have a syntax error it will show up in your browser's Console

Comment: Anyway, assuming there's no other error... since you haven't shown enough of the relevant code we can't really say why things aren't happening. Have you tried using the browser's debugger as well? Or doing some simple console logging to see if events are being fired etc?

Comment: After further debugging the JQuery functions do in fact fire.  In addition, if I remove the "hidden" from the divs and then change the Jquery to do: .hide() it does in fact hide the divs, but .show() does not do the reverse and reveal.  I tried putting class="invisible" for the divs to see if maybe that would work but it does not.  Is using "hidden" and class="invisible" a good approach to this? Maybe is there a way to make the divs hidden via the OnGet?  Also let me know what other relevant code you would like to see.

Comment: Mainly the relevant HTML and CSS, so that we can reproduce the problem. The divs you're talking about, and the CSS classes you're talking about. Otherwise it's hard to know how everything is interacting to produce these results

Comment: The divs are already included and I have not created new CSS classes, "invisible" was a bootstrap class.  I have added the html for Category and SubCategory as well as how they are initialized with the code behind.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry yes the divs are there already. But adding the category / subcategory stuff was useful. And mentioning bootstrap is important - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal demo of your scenario using completely static data - your basic concept is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/f7j6vgmo/ .

But if we add Bootstrap in, it stops working: https://jsfiddle.net/f7j6vgmo/1/

This seems to be because bootstrap adds `!important` to the CSS definition for the `hidden` attribute. This is visible in the browser's element inspector if you look at one of the elements marked as hidden (even after it's been the subject of a `.show()` command):

```
[hidden] {
    display: none!important;
```

The source of that rule is given as `reboot.scss` which is part of Bootstrap. The rule makes the `display:none;` override the `display:block` rule set by running the `.show()` method. (Normally, setting the `display` property overrides the `hidden` attribute, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)).

The simplest alternative is to replace the `hidden` attributes with `style="display:none;"`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f7j6vgmo/2/